# Почему ширина блока в JavaScript API Яндекс Карт v3 не уменьшается при уменьшении размера экрана?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть такой родительский блок, куда рендерится модуль яндекс карт:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
    <ymaps is="ymaps" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block;"></ymaps>
</div>
```

Внутри блока тега `ymaps`, с не совсем понятным атрибутом `is="ymaps"`, есть такой блок, где изменяются размеры карты в зависимости от ширины контейнера:

```
<ymaps class="ymaps3x0--map" style="width: 588px; height: 400px; touch-action: none;"></ymaps>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что карта расширяется при увеличении ширины браузера, но не сужается при уменьшении.

Это баг или я что-то делаю не так? как исправить?

Comment: Проверьте, изменяется ли размер родительского блока при уменьшении ширины окна? Карта сама должна подстраивать свою ширину. Если все блоки уменьшаются, а карта — нет, нужен минимальный рабочий пример кода для анализа.

Comment: @YaSupport, Спасибо за ответ! Разобрался. Проблема была с тем, что не указал width для определенных родительских элементов.